# Change start-up options for mysqld in whm on CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos, whm

I have a WHM/Cpanel server set up on CentOS 7.6.

I need to set up my mysqld process with a start-up option --init-file, to be ran every time the service is restarted.

I assume there is a file somewhere on the server that tells WHM what options to use when starting the service mysqld. But I can't find it.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that CentOS uses the systemd service initializer.

Answer:
Edit the mysqld.service file in
/usr/lib/systemd/system

Then you have to reload the systemctl daemon. Run command:
systemctl daemon-reload

Then restart mysql from WHM and it will execute the option

Comment: If you want to run MySQL as a normal user on CentOS, then you can set the User and Group properties in the [Service] section of the /usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service file.  Setting user=X in my.cnf as described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/changing-mysql-user.html will NOT work on CentOS with WHM/cPanel. You will see a "One can only use the --user switch if running as root" warning in mysqld.log and the startup will abort.